# Selecting item from database plus all dependencies

Tags: entity-framework

Im trying to select all items in a database aswel as all its dependencies using the entity framework.

I get the following error doing the select 
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'RequestModel.RequestType' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'FieldDefinitions,ListItems'.

Here is my code, Im sure its something simple im missing.

```
    var reqs = new List<RequestType>();

    using (var db = new ITISS_RequestEntities())
    {

        reqs = db.RequestTypes.Include("FieldDefinitions,ListItems").ToList();
    }
```

Here is my models

```
    public partial class RequestType
    {
        public RequestType()
        {
            this.Requests = new HashSet<Request>();
            this.FieldDefinitions = new HashSet<FieldDefinition>();
        }

        public int RequestType1 { get; set; }
        public string TypeDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FieldDefinition> FieldDefinitions { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class FieldDefinition
    {
        public FieldDefinition()
        {
            this.EntryDefinitions = new HashSet<EntryDefinition>();
            this.ListItems = new HashSet<ListItem>();
            this.RequestTypes = new HashSet<RequestType>();
        }

        public int RequestField { get; set; }
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string FieldReference { get; set; }
        public string ControlType { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<EntryDefinition> EntryDefinitions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RequestType> RequestTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class ListItem
    {
        public ListItem()
        {
            this.FieldDefinitions = new HashSet<FieldDefinition>();
        }

        public int ListItemID { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FieldDefinition> FieldDefinitions { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're using virtual ICollections so everything should be available through Lazy Loading anyway.

If you actually want to force a single load of the entire tree then change this

```
reqs = db.RequestTypes.Include("FieldDefinitions,ListItems").ToList();
```

to this

```
reqs = db.RequestTypes.Include("FieldDefinitions").Select("ListItems").ToList();
```

Also, if you add

```
using System.Data.Entity
```

to the top of your file you'll be able to use the strongly-typed extension methods for Include.....hence.....

```
reqs = db.RequestTypes.Include(rt => rt.FieldDefinitions).Select(fd => fd.ListItems).ToList();
```

In fact [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) is a really useful page for Entity Framework queries

Comment: Just to make things alittle clearer, Im using the Entity Framework 5. The options you mentioned is for the Entity Framework 6. Getting The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TResult>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: You can use them just fine in EF5 if you include the "using" at the top - as I specified :)

Comment: Thanks for that, tho your linq didnt work due to RequestType not containing a definition for ListItems

Comment: I tried tweaking it to reqs = db.RequestTypes.Include(rt => rt.FieldDefinitions).Select(fd => fd.FieldDefinitions.Select(li => li.ListItems)).ToList();

Comment: Now its only selecting a collection ListItems and nothing else

Comment: Oops.  OK, Here's one of mine, from my code - it could be brackets, or perhaps you don't need the subselects?
    var entity = dataContext.Set<StudyDomainLevel>().Where(sdl => sdl.StudyDomainLevelId == studyDomainLevelId)
                .Include(a => a.Descendants.Select(c => c.Answers.Select(b => b.Question)))
                .Include(a => a.Study.SurveyTemplate.QuestionGroups.Select(ig => ig.Group.Questions.Select(q => q.Question.Type)))
                .SingleOrDefault();